# Find out whether its a search result page or a link loaded in a UIwebview?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I  had an application in which i am using UIWebview for loading the webpages. I had a footer for my UIwebview.I need to change it for search results and link loading.I had done this in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But when i am returning from the loaded link {through history [goBack]}its not changing properly.Can anybody guide me how to find whether we are loading search results or a link.?

Comment: Some more details... you are loading a webpage and want to react different, when a link gets clicked? You are talking about search results.. what search results?? And when/where do you call goBack.. please describe more.

Comment: @jaydee3 i am loading ggoogle.com first(by default).so that user can search on it as like our webbroser.untill he was finalising a link.ie(you are typing anything on the search bar it will show you the search results)thats a page is it?then from there we are choosing the link.so when we come back from that link to the searched page i need a different footer